# can we convert text to voice or viceversa?

Tags: java, blackberry, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

hie,
can we convert text to voice and voice to text in blackberry?
is there any api present for doing this?
i have seen some apps in market who is doing the same?
how we can convert text to voice plz help me?
thnks..

Answer (score 1):

[Java Media Speech](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/)